# Aptana - Open Declaration

Tags: javascript, find, aptana

So I downloaded Aptana because many people have said it is the best IDE for javascript. Grabbed a project off github, went to a line in the code that was a method call, right clicked on it and noticed 'open declaration - F3'. Tried both it and F3 with absolutely no response from Aptana....Aptana uninstalled.

Out of curiosity is there any way in Aptana to go from a method call or variable to its declaration? If something that is version 3 cannot do this out-of-the-box, makes me wonder why the hype?

Comment: FYI: I've used Aptana a long time, but replaced it with Komodo-Edit (http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit). Aptana is slow (esp. syntax checking with large js-files) and with every new build something else seemed to be broken.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The slow syntax checking was largely due to JSLint/Rhino performance, and we've addressed that in upcoming versions.

Answer (score 0):

I too recently tried out version 3 after being dissapointed with v2 a while ago.

Open declaration works, if the method is in the same file.. otherwise it fails across multiple files in the same project.

That concludes the answer portion, rest is just my angry rant:

What is even worse that with HOVER on the function call it actually shows the location where the function is located, that is it shows exact directory and file name, yet F3 or open declaration does nothing as OP said.

This means, that there has to be some way of triggering the function lookup across other files in the same project.

How can it be that Aptana knows where the function is located, yet is unable to open it within the same project?

Where are you APTANA developers?

Comment: I tried to recreate this issue (and fix it), but at least on the latest nightly version it's working fine. If you can provide us some files to demo that, it would be very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Made new general project, created two .js files in the project (in the same directory no less) each containing a single function (TestA, TestB), both called from the first file. Hover on the function calls shows the location for both, but F3 only works on the function which is in the same file. This is on build: 3.2.0.201206251729

Comment: General project does not hold the Aptana Web Nature that is needed. Try creating a new Web Project, or go to the project's properties and locate the Natures page. In there, check the 'Web' nature option and apply the change.

Comment: Changed the general project nature to have web as primary and applied. Still the same behaviour, restarted Aptana, no improvement.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can do this though it's not perfect. If you see that it's finding a path to the function, ctrl+hover over the function and it should pop down a list of paths to places where the function was defined in your workspace. Click on one and it will jump you to that declaration.